# How to generate CSS content with a SASS for loop

Tags: css, for-loop, sass

I'm trying to create a SASS mixin that would operate like this:

```
@include custom-horiz-sep(7);
```

which would output CSS:

```
content: "xxxxxxx";
```

(7 pre-defined characters)

How would I use a 'for' loop in SASS to create the value for the "content" property?

Comment: @cimmanon I'm actually curious about your thoughts. In Ruby, we could just do `"x"*7`. Sass doesn't like that. [This](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/EcfrD) is as close as I could get.

Comment: I would have just done concatenation starting with an empty string, rather than using a list.

Comment: @bookcasey -- That's pretty much it, I'd say, apart from the extraneous space that's getting generated in the string. Why would the `append($content, x)` bit create that extra space? Regardless, good work, and many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

With bookcasey and cimmanon's help, here's what seems to work great:

```
@mixin custom-horiz-sep($num) {
  $chr: "x";
  $content: $chr;
  @for $i from 0 to $num {
      $content: $content + $chr;
  }
  content: "#{$content}";
}

h1:before {
  @include custom-horiz-sep(25);
}
```

http://codepen.io/Protohominid/pen/rgzKF